# How to monitor multiple Kubernetes clusters using single Grafana?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, thanos

I would like to use a single Grafana instance to monitor multiple Kubernetes cluster (pods resources consumption, rabbitmq queues info) provided by Prometheus. I have two Kubernetes cluster - one used for monitoring and common workload and the other for specific - sensitive - workload.

##### Basic info

- I do not want to use Prometheus (in cluster 2) as data source in Grafana (*use Federation*), because I want to keep cluster 2 isolation at maximum (**no ingress** or other public endpoints)
- I will be fine using two data sources in Grafana (cluster 1, cluster 2)
- I have found [thanos.io](https://thanos.io/), but I am not sure if it's the right path

Can you help me with the solution design, please?

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; you may use Thanos.io for your use case, specifically Thanos Receivers. These are designed to collect metrics through egress-only connections.

The general idea is to install the Thanos Receiver in your Cluster 1 and then configure Prometheus in Cluster 2 to use the `remote_write` functionality to send the scraped metrics to the Thanos Receiver in Cluster 1. Then, you set up the Thanos Querier to access the data for visualization in Grafana.

You can check out tutorials from KillerKoda to practice, as they are [recommended in the Thanos documentation](https://thanos.io/tip/thanos/quick-tutorial.md/).

Comment: I have ended up with the exactly same configuration, as you mentioned.